# Limit of a sequence of real numbers 2

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, integer-sequences

I want to show using the definition of limit of a sequence that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{ne^{-n}}=0.$$

Here $0\notin\mathbb{N}$. This is my attemp:

We note that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}{ne^{-n}}=0 \iff \forall\epsilon>0 :\exists N\in\mathbb{N} : \forall n\geq N : |ne^{-n}-0|<\epsilon.
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
&|ne^{-n}-0|<\epsilon\\
&\iff |ne^{-n}|<\epsilon\\
&\iff \left|\frac{n}{e^n}\right|<\epsilon
\end{align*}
since $n$ must be more than a natural number, we have that $n/e^n>0$, so
\begin{align*}
&\frac{n}{e^n}<\epsilon\\
&\implies \ln\left(\frac{n}{e^n}\right)<\epsilon\\
&\implies \ln(n)-\ln(e^n)<\ln(\epsilon)\\
&\implies \ln(n)-n<\ln(\epsilon)\leq \epsilon -1\\
&\implies \frac{n-1}{n}<\ln(n)<n+\epsilon-1\\
&\implies \frac{n-1}{n}<n+\epsilon-1\\
&\implies n-1<n^2+n\epsilon-n\\
&\implies n^2+n\epsilon-n-n+1>0\\
&\implies n^2+n(\epsilon-2)+1>0 \Longleftrightarrow:\varphi
\end{align*}
I can´t see how I can get something useful from $\varphi$. Can anyones help to find the way please?
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

I like your initiative, but there's a serious and fundamental problem with this attempt: the direction of the logic. Remember, you need $n / e^n < \varepsilon$ to be the conclusion of your logic, not the premise. It's fine to work from this proposition, but if you do, each step should logically imply the *previous* step, not the next step. For example, where you state
$$\ln(n)-\ln(e^n)<\ln(\varepsilon) \implies \ln(n)-n < \varepsilon -1,$$
this is an example where the logic does not flow in the correct direction. While this implication is valid, it is not helpful. We are interested in statements that imply $\ln(n)-\ln(e^n)<\ln(\varepsilon)$, not its consequences.

If you want information on how to tackle this well, you can check out [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2506694/limit-of-the-sequence-fracnan-for-a1?noredirect=1). I'm sure there are others on this site too. Often, this is done with squeeze theorem. Other approaches, using heavier machinery, involve l'Hopital's rule (showing the stronger result that $\lim_{x \to \infty} xe^{-x} = 0$, where $x \in \Bbb{R}$), or by proving $\sum ne^{-n}$ is a convergent series using one of the many tests, and using the fact that terms of convergent series must tend to $0$.

Comment: P.S. I like the $:\iff$ symbol. It's totally non-standard, but I knew what you meant as soon as you used it. The only problem is, surely it should be $\iff:$, as $\varphi$ is what you're defining?

Comment: Yes, it should be $\Longleftrightarrow :$, thank you so much!